# What are the ages?

Tags: problem-solving

A man taking the census walks up to the apartment of a mathematician and asks him if he has any children and how old they are.

1. The mathematician says: "${\it\mbox{I have three daughters and the product
           of their ages  is 72}}$".
2. The man tells the mathematician that he needs more information, so
           the mathematician tells him ${\it\mbox{"The sum of their ages is equal to
           our apartment number"}}$.
3. The man still needs more information so the mathematician tells him
                ${\it\mbox{"My oldest daughter has her own bed and the other two
                share bunk beds"}}$.

Comment: What's the apartment number?

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that the census-taker has enough information after the mathematician's last answer?  Also, you should put the question in the question body, even though it is already in the title.

Comment: Is the fact that they two youngest daughters share a bunk bed supposed to imply that they are twins?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that implies they are twins.

Comment: I vote $3,4,6$ with apartment number $13$...

Comment: Is the census-taker a 'perfect-logical' being in the sense that he can always deduce everything that there is to be infered and is he incable of lying? For instance, when he says he doesn't have enough information, is that necessarily true?

Comment: I don't think the mathematician's last statement is supposed to imply that the youngest two daughters are the same age, only that there is a unique oldest daughter.

Comment: @muffle got the right idea.

Answer (score 4):

By examination, there are $12$ integer triplets that multiply to $72$.

Ten of them have unique sums, so if any of these were the solution, the census taker would not be in ignorance of the triplet, once he knew the sum

Two triplets, $(2,6,6)$ and $(3,3,8)$ both add to $14$.  Once the professor implies that he has an ***oldest*** daughter, the choice is uniquely defined...

Edited to correct inability to count rows in a spreadsheet....

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of anything really elegant. Just write down all possible ways of writing 72 as a product of three numbers. Then write the sum of each triplet. The correct answer would be that triplet in which the smallest number occurs exactly twice and no other triplet with this property exists whose sum is same as the sum of elements in this triplet.

Comment: Does your solution include 1, 1, and 72?

Comment: I think that a 72-year old daughter would be a little old...

Comment: But it ***would*** satisfy the above analysis.

Comment: The 72 year old could be the biological daughter and the two young ones could be adopted. You never know. Like what if the guy was one of those Hollywood celebrities?

Comment: 1. 1 year olds are not put on bunk beds. 2. If the man had a 72 year old daughter, would he be alive? Very unlikely.